# VB Access DB Update statement

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I am new to this forum, please could you help me get this code to work, when i execute it, it simply does nothing and does not update the DB. If i remove the square brackets it gives an error: "SYNTAX ERROR in UPDATE statement"
Any help appreciated!

```vb
Dim connection As OleDbConnection
connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=UserDB.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database;")
connection.Open()

Dim pass As String
pass = txtconfirm.Text
Dim user As String
user = LoginForm.UsernameTextBox.Text

Dim query As String = "UPDATE [Users] SET [Password]= '" & pass & "' WHERE [Username]= '" & user & "';"

Dim command As New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
connection.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your actual connection string, the database that will be updated is the one in the directory where your application starts. This means that if you work with a WinForms application this folder is \BIN\DEBUG or x86 variant. If there is not error then you could get the return value of the ExecuteNonQuery call to verify if a record has been updated or not

```
 Dim rowsUpdated = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
 MessageBox.Show("Record updated count = " & rowsUpdated)
```

If this value is not zero then your database has been updated and you are looking for changes in the wrong database. Check the one in the BIN\DEBUG folder.

In any case your code has big problems. If your variables `user` or `pass` contain a single quote, then your code will crash again because your string concatenation will form an invalid SQL. As usual the only workaround is to use a parameterized query

```
Dim pass = txtconfirm.Text
Dim user = LoginForm.UsernameTextBox.Text
Dim query As String = "UPDATE [Users] SET [Password]= @p1 WHERE [Username]= @p2"
Using connection = New OleDbConnection("...........")
Using command As New OleDbCommand(query, connection)
    connection.Open()
    command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = pass
    command.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = user
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
```

The parameterized approach has many advantages. Your query text is more readable, there is no misunderstanding between your code and the values expected by your database engine. And while not easy to exploit with MS-Access there is no problem with Sql Injection

Comment: Thanks to the reply, your answer partially worked, when i checked the debug database the password has changed. When i close the program I have to enter the original password again. How can i get it so it changes permanently?? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Do you have your database file listed between your project files? If yes check the value of the property Copy To Output Directory. If it is set to Copy Always then every time you restart your debug session the file is copied from the project folder to the debug folder overwriting the one there (of course destroying your previous change) And remember that the simple act of opening an access database file changes its datetime causing the If Newer flag to kick in

Answer (score 0):

I think Steve presents a much better approach for you coding this...
Let me just throw out a few more things:
The reason you can't take those brackets out is some of your column names are reserved words; just FYI.
Since you report "it does nothing..." when you execute, it sounds like you have a valid connection and sql syntax, in which case my next step would be to copy the sql command text while in debug mode, change it to a select and run it in your DB.  You should get one result when you do.  If not, either your criteria or field contents are not what you think they are...
Just change the `Update table SET field-value ...` to `SELECT * FROM table` and leave the `WHERE` clause as is.

Comment: Oops, my editor was open for a while and I had to do some other stuff... sorry to post on an answered post